# How to create dynamic checkboxes on Winform by passing checkbox name in List C#?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, winforms, excel-addins

I'm working on excel add-in project c#.

want to create list of checkboxes with name which is passed in List , how can I create it with that pass named?

and want to take that check box selected value also.

Currently I have one button `LoadEmployee` when I clicked on that all EmployeeNames gets loaded into Excel sheet from Sql table directly

Now I want to do when I clicked on `LoadEmployee` it will open one popup with all employee names and every emplyee name has one check box , which one i select that employee name is populated only not other.

With the help of answer given by @Vajura I tried like

called popup form using

```
 new FilterDataForm().ShowDialog(mylist);
```

on popup form .cs

```
internal void ShowDialog(MyModel.ListEmployee> mylist)
    {
        GenerateFilterList(mylist);            
    }

 private void GenerateFilterList(List<ListEmployee> mylist)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox box;
            for (int i = 0; i < mylist.Count; i++)
            {
                box = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
                box.Tag = mylist[i];
                box.Text = mylisti].ToString();
                box.AutoSize = true;
                box.Location = new Point(10, i * 50); //vertical
                //box.Location = new Point(i * 50, 10); //horizontal
                this.Controls.Add(box);
            }
        }
```

> butthen also not getting any popup :(

Check this screenshot i'm looking for output like this on popup `Employee names` will be displayed which is passed by using `LIST`[image]

Comment: Please attach the screen shot...

Comment: please check screenshot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already have a list with the employe names? Then simply do this

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Size = new Size(200, 200);
    List<string> yourList = new List<string>();
    yourList.Add("A");
    yourList.Add("B");
    yourList.Add("C");
    yourList.Add("D");
    yourList.Add("E");
    yourList.Add("F");
    CheckBox box;
    int innitialOffset = 20;
    int xDistance = 80;
    int yDistance = 50;

    for (int i = 0; i < yourList.Count; i++)
    {
        box = new CheckBox();
        box.Tag = yourList[i];
        box.Text = yourList[i].ToString();
        box.AutoSize = true;
        box.Location = new Point(innitialOffset + i % 2 * xDistance, innitialOffset + i / 2 * yDistance); 

        this.Controls.Add(box);
    }
}
```

Comment: but how these all checkboxes will appear on that particular popup Form? I need to write this code on initialize method of Form?

Comment: Dont they already appear on the form or are you asking to put them on the form in that grid like you have?

Comment: Changed my answear, is this what you wanted?

Comment: thanks for answer please check updated answer - not getting any popup might i left something small

Comment: you mean the form with the checkboxes doesnt open? Also you pass **mylist** to the function but then use **entities** whats the **mylist** for then?

Comment: Personally I'd use one of the containers to contain all dynamically created controls. This also makes alignment easier, since you might be able to get it done automatically.

Comment: @vajura yea its bymistake entities i have used mylist only . i wonder why pop up does not come. should I need to call my checkbox methos on FORM_LOAD() ? is it

Comment: I still dont know what exactly the problem is? With popup do you mean this form with the checkboxes on it? If it doesnt show up then the event where you are calling it isnt getting triggered

Comment: problem is I'm uanble to pass LIST in a variable from where I called like `new FilterDataForm().ShowDialog();`
if i passed LIST as a variable in ShowDIalog() popup does not appear

Comment: is you FilterDataForm static? Why dont you create a object of it and call it then? But i think it should work like this too. You would probably need to post more of your code

Comment: checkboxes are not shown in the form may i know how to make it displayed?